# Compare neighbors in array

Tags: python, algorithm, array

I have a a python function for taking in a 2D numpy array and checking if each element is the same as its neighbor elements. I feel like there's a more efficient way to do this but I'm not sure. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

def compare_neighbors(arr):
    '''
    Checks if element (i,j) is different than (i-1,j),(i+1,j),(i,j-1), or 
    (i,j+1).

    --Input--
    arr: (2D np.array) array to compare all elements of

    --Returns--
    comp_arr: (2D bool np.array) bool array with the resulting comparisons.
           True means the original element is the same as its neighbors,
           False means it was different than at least neighbor
    '''
    comp_arr = np.full(arr.shape, False, dtype=bool) #initialize
    arr_height = arr.shape[0]
    arr_width = arr.shape[1]

    for i in range(arr_height): #Row
        for j in range(arr_width): #column

            center = arr[i,j]

            #Check edges
            if i == 0: #left side
                left = arr[i,j]
            else:
                left = arr[i-1, j]

            if i == arr_height - 1: #right side
                right = arr[i,j]
            else:
                right = arr[i+1,j]

            if j == 0: #up
                up = arr[i,j]
            else:
                up = arr[i, j-1]

            if j == arr_width - 1: #down
                down = arr[i,j]
            else:
                down = arr[i, j+1]

            comp_arr[i,j] = len(set([left, right, up, down, center])) == 1
    return comp_arr
```

If it is helpful, here are the tests I used for testing it:

```
A = np.array([[1,1],
              [1,1]])

comp_arr_A = compare_neighbors(A)

B = np.array([[2,2],
              [2,2]])

comp_arr_B = compare_neighbors(B)

C = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
              [1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1],
              [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
              [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]])

comp_arr_C = compare_neighbors(C)

D = np.array([[1,1,1],
              [1,2,1],
              [1,1,1]])

comp_arr_D = compare_neighbors(D)

print(A)
print()
print(comp_arr_A)
print()
print(B)
print()
print(comp_arr_B)
print()
print(C)
print()
print(comp_arr_C)
print()
print(D)
print()
print(comp_arr_D)
```

which returns

```
[[1 1]
 [1 1]]

[[ True  True]
 [ True  True]]

[[2 2]
 [2 2]]

[[ True  True]
 [ True  True]]

[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1]
 [1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1]
 [1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]

[[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True False False False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False False False  True]]

[[1 1 1]
 [1 2 1]
 [1 1 1]]

[[ True False  True]
 [False False False]
 [ True False  True]]
```

as expected. All I need the function to do is check each element and compare it to its left, right, above, and bellow neighbors. If it is the same as them then the compare_array in that index is True and if it is different than any of its neighbors then False.

Comment: Maybe this is a case for a filter: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can improve iterating over the array by using `np.ndenumerate` to get the current coordinates and current item. From the coordinates you can derive the neighbouring elements.
You can also use inverse checking to only set the respective field to `False` if a neighbor does not match:

```
from contextlib import suppress

def compare_neighbors(arr):

    comp_arr = np.full(arr.shape, True, dtype=bool)

    for (x, y), item in np.ndenumerate(arr):
        # Check left.
        if x >= 0:
            if arr[x-1, y] != item:
                comp_arr[x, y] = False
                continue

        # Check right.
        with suppress(IndexError):
            if arr[x+1, y] != item:
                comp_arr[x, y] = False
                continue

        # Check top.
        with suppress(IndexError):
            if arr[x, y+1] != item:
                comp_arr[x, y] = False
                continue

        # Check bottom.
        if y >= 0:
            if arr[x, y-1] != item:
                comp_arr[x, y] = False
                continue

    return comp_arr
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `np.roll` function if you have a bigger array like in a [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33766/how-to-compare-fast-the-value-with-the-ones-of-neighbours-in-a-3d-array?noredirect=1#comment39733_33766) by doing:

```
import numpy as np
def shift_helper(array, shift=0, axis=0):
    # Roll the array by n unity along one axis
    _array = np.roll(_array, shift=shift, axis=axis)

    # Cancel the last/first slice rolled to the first/last slice
        if axis == 0:
            if shift >= 0:
                _array[:1, :, :] = False
            else:
                _array[-1:, :, :] = False
            return _array
        elif axis == 1:
            if shift >= 0:
                _array[:, :1, :] = False
            else:
                _array[:, -1:, :] = False
            return _array

        #Uncomment it for 3D array
        #elif axis == 2:
            #if shift >= 0:
                #_array[:, :, :1] = False
            #else:
                #_array[:, :, -1:] = False
            #return _array

def compare(array, that_value):
    bool_array = np.zeros(array.shape, dtype=bool)
    bool_array[np.where((array == that_value)
                        & (shift_helper(array!=that_value, shift=1, axis=0)#up
                        | shift_helper(array!=that_value, shift=-1, axis=0)#down
                        | shift_helper(array!=that_value, shift=1, axis=1)#left
                        | shift_helper(array!=that_value, shift=-1, axis=1)#right
                        #Uncomment below for 3D array
                        #| shift_helper(array!=that_value, shift=1, axis=2)#front
                        #| shift_helper(array!=that_value, shift=-1, axis=2)#back
                ))] = True
    return bool_array
# Main
C = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
              [1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1],
              [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
              [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]])
print(compare(C, 1))
print(compare(C, 2))
```

You can choose the value that you want to compare and extend to 3D with this.